# Spring MVC controller Test - print the result JSON String

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, junit4

Hi I have a Spring mvc controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/jobsdetails/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Jobs> jobsDetails(@PathVariable Integer userId,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try {       
        Map<String, Object> queryParams=new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(); 

        queryParams.put("userId", userId);

        jobs=jobsService.findByNamedQuery("findJobsByUserId", queryParams);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return jobs;
}
```

I want to see how the JSON String will looks like when I run this. I wrote this test case

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("classpath:webapptest")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-applicationcontext.xml"})
public class FindJobsControllerTest {
private MockMvc springMvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wContext;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void documentsPollingTest() throws Exception {
        ResultActions resultActions = springMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/jobsdetails/2").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        System.out.println(/* Print the JSON String */); //How ?
    }
}
```

How to get the JSON string?

I am using Spring 3, codehause Jackson 1.8.4

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Try this code:

```
resultActions.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
```

Comment: Thank you for not just using `print()` but adding its class name, unlike many other search results!

Answer (score 74):

The trick is to use `andReturn()`

```
MvcResult result = springMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
         .get("/jobsdetails/2").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();

String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Answer (score 24):

You can enable printing response of each test method when setting up the `MockMvc` instance.

```
springMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wContext)
               .alwaysDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
               .build();
```

Notice the `.alwaysDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())` part of the above code. This way you can avoid applying print handler for each test method.

Answer (score 10):

For me it worked when I used the code below:

```
ResultActions result =
     this.mockMvc.perform(post(resource).sessionAttr(Constants.SESSION_USER, user).param("parameter", "parameterValue"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
String content = result.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

And it worked !! :D

Hope I can help the other with my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing the Controller, you won't get the JSon result, which is returned by the view. Whether you can test the view (or test the controller and then the view), or starting a servlet contrainer (with Cargo for example), and test at HTTP level, which is a good way to check what really happen.

Comment: Actually you can get the JSON response from the controller using .andReturn()

Comment: Oh yes, that's true, I just saw this in your answer. I didn't know Spring offered so much mocks, that's very great.

Answer (score 0):

For modern projects using Spring Boot, where `MockMvc` is already pre-configured for you with a single `@WebMvcTest` "slicing" test annotation, the easiest answer to the question would be explicitly adding `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` with `printOnlyOnFailure = false`:

```java
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(printOnlyOnFailure = false)
class MySlicedControllerTest {
  // ...
}
```