# Test a method that returns a ResponseEntity from a service class - Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, mockmvc

I have a service method which returns a ResponseEntity<>, when I am testing the rest endpoint it always returns below error.The error says that it haven't return the expected json.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.status"
```

This is the method I'am using

```java
    @Test
    void Should_ReturnOk_When_VerifyOtpIsSuccessful() throws Exception {

        ResponseWrapper responseWrapper =
                new ResponseWrapper(ResponseStatusType.SUCCESS, "SUCCESSFULLY_VERIFIED", null);

        ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper> responseWrapperResponseEntity =new ResponseEntity<>(responseWrapper,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

        when(otpService.verifySmsOtp(otpVerifyRequestDto)).thenReturn(responseWrapperResponseEntity);

        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post(OTP_VERIFY_URI)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("app-key", "xxxx")
                .content(asJsonString(otpVerifyRequestDto)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", is("S")))
        ;
    }
```

Here ResponseWrapper is a model class

```java
@Getter
public class ResponseWrapper {

    private ResponseStatusType status;
    private String message;
    private String data;


    public ResponseWrapper(ResponseStatusType statusType, String message, String data) {
        this.status = statusType;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Could you help me out to sort this issue.

Edited:

Seems like the ResponseEntity does not return the JSON itself, it have other objects [image]

Appreciate your input on this.

Test Class Initialization

```java
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class OtpControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private OtpServiceImpl otpService;
    private Validator validator = new Validator();
    private OtpRequestDto otpRequestDtoEmail = otpRequestDto();
    private OtpVerifyRequestDto otpVerifyRequestDto = otpVerifyRequestDto();

    @InjectMocks
    private OtpController otpController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        otpController = new OtpController(otpService, validator);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(otpController).build();
    }

// test methods here
//
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried printing the JSON to check how it looks manually? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495296/spring-mvc-controller-test-print-the-result-json-string)

Comment: Printed, but the body is empty, and i debugged the code inside the when(), their is json inside.

Comment: Where do you set the body of your `responseWrapperResponseEntity`?

Comment: @Smutje here                                                          
ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper> responseWrapperResponseEntity =new ResponseEntity<>(responseWrapper,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

Comment: What is a `ResponseWrapper` and where does it produce JSON? This is not a verifiable minimal example.

Comment: @Smutje sorry for the confusion, here ResponseWrapper is a model class. I have updated the question.

Comment: Can you provide the essentials of the test class, How is the class annotated, what do you init in `@Before` method, how do you init mocks?